# How to write a query for the below scenario?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Please tell me the below scenario.

Table  :

```
Id appName        role    Type    Status      createdAt
1  application1  role1   false    completed   25/05/2014 12.00.00
2  application1  role1   true     completed   25/05/2014 11.00.00
3  application1  role1   true     completed   25/05/2014 11.00.00
4  application2  role1   true     completed   25/05/2014 11.00.00
5  application2  role1   false    completed   25/05/2014 10.00.00
```

in above table i need the output like

```
output:
Id appName        role    Type    Status      createdAt
4  application2  role1   true     completed   25/05/2014 11.00.00
```

I don't want application1 because its type is false and createAt latest.
If application1 type is true and it is latest then we should display that record.
please tell me how to write the query in linq to sql.

concern:latest record type false then no need to display the matching records.in above table
application1 type is false and it is latest then no need to display 1,2,3.
application2 type is true and it is latest so display that record only 4.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Do your query in 2 steps: first select all latest record for your key. Then from the latest records select the ones that have the correct status.

Answer (score 0):

```
(from d in context.Table
group d by d.appName into g
select g.OrderByDescending(gg=>gg.createdAt).Take(1))//should give you latest for each appname
.Where(dd=>dd.Type == true)//should filter out the ones with Type being False
```